# Tell if a page is in memory?

Tags: c, unix

Is there a way to tell (on UNIXes) which of a process's memory pages are in the RAM and which have been swapped out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no portable way. You can *prevent* pages from being swapped out with `mlock` or `mlockall` (but this needs sufficient permissions), or you could use a non-portable method. On Linux, the `kpageflags` file in `/proc`, along with the `pagemap` file in your process's directory under `/proc`, should be sufficient to give you the information. They're documented in the Linux source's `Documentation` tree.

Comment: This could be useful, is /proc always on main memory?

Comment: `/proc` doesn't actually exist on disk or in memory at all; it's *generated* at runtime when a process reads from it. Even though the files show up as ordinary files they behave more like pipes in this regard. The only issue is that resolving the name `/proc` under `/` might require access to `/`, but on a realtime system this could probably be handed by making `/` a small ramdisk with most of the actual filesystem contents on `/usr` or such.

Answer (score 2):

Not in a portable way.

Even if it were possible, it would be mostly useless. A page you have checked is swapped in could very well be swapped out the moment you are ready to use it.

Comment: There is a race-free way to handle this situation: if the page is reported as in-memory, request that a helper thread call `mlock` on the page (so that you don't block) and use a "try" or "timed"-type synchronization primitive to check for bounded-time success. After that, you can be sure that accessing the page won't incur IO and possibly-unbounded blocking. When you're done, you can `munlock` the page to hand responsibility back to the kernel.